# How do I associate the right Contact Card under Users & Groups to my own profile?

Tags: macos, contacts

Just got a Mac for the first time...

Under System Preferences > Users & Groups, I have a user profile set as the Admin.

My Full Name and Apple ID are shown correctly. However, when I click on the "Open" button next to "Contacts Card", it thinks that this user profile is associated to the contact card of another member of the family. How do I change that to my own Contact Card?

The consequences of this wrong profile is that whenever I install a new software and I get asked for my name, it keeps putting the name of the family member by default. I also had to go back into my Mail, Contacts & Calendars settings where the full name field was filled out with the family member's name although the accounts were set up correctly.

Comment: Actually, I figured it out! I logged onto iCloud.com, clicked on Contacts and there was an option to change the "me" profile to my actual contact card.

Comment: welcome to the site - can you post your comment here as an answer?   (And then you can accept it if you want.)  Once it's an answer, we'll delete these comments.

Comment: Is this question specific to OS X?  Or is it a problem across your Apple devices?

Comment: My problem... My own contact card disappeared from time to time. So, the ability to "choose" that contact card was not possible. I had to go to my iMac and choose there. The other possibility was go to iCloud

Answer (score 21):

You don't need iCloud.com to do this.  Open the Contacts application, select your card entry, click on the Card menu, choose "Make this My Card"

Answer (score 5):

I ran across this issue when restoring a backup to a new phone. 
It was showing another family member's contact as My Card under Contacts.
iCloud wasn't even signed in.

I had to go into Settings > Mail, Contacts, Calendars. Scroll down to Contacts and select the correct contact under My Info.

iPhone 6 with iOS 9.

Comment: Where is this option in iOS 11?

Answer (score 0):

I know this thread is a bit old, but I've run into a similar issue and this thread is showing high on the search results both here and through Google.

We recently switched to Family Sharing, and the problem was on one of the devices that recently transitioned to a new AppleID.  Regardless of the setting for "My Card" on the device, apps still pulled info from the "My Card" of the original shared AppleID.

We could not get the "My Card" setting to stick across the board.  The contacts app would show the correct "My Card", but apps would pull data from another card.  Also, from time to time, the "My Card" setting in Contacts would switch back to the original card.  We had to use the iCloud.Com web interface to make the "My Card" setting stick across the board.

Answer (score -1):

Go to setting...mail,contac,calendars.... Scroll down to where is says "my info" select your contact card and you are done. Hope it helps